# Why does my Github webhook keep timing out?

Tags: github

```
We couldn’t deliver this payload: Service Timeout
```

I was successfully sending webooks to my server 5 minutes ago, and now I just keep getting timeouts. I tried deleting the webook and re-adding it, changing the URL it points to, but nothing.

Am I flooding it with too many pushes, or is GitHub's webhook service just down?

Comment: can you show here format of url enpoints which you tried.

Comment: is your server in AWS or any other cloud?

Answer (score 4):

It also turns out that GitHub has a 10-second timeout set on their webhooks.  That is what I ran into.  See the documentation [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/best-practices-for-integrators/#favor-asynchronous-work-over-synchronous).

Comment: Did you do anything to get around that 10-second timeout?

Comment: Speed up the processing on my end.  That is all you could do (at the time).  I don't know if they have improved this at all.

Comment: For what its worth, one of the best ways to speed up processing is by doing your calculating asynchronously.  What ever the long tasks are, queue them and return a response to github.

Answer (score 3):

Unless there is some kind of error on the GitHub side (which doesn't seem to be the case at the moment, given their ["System Status" history](https://status.github.com/messages)), you might check the program receiving the payload of that webhook.

See a similar problem in [Supybot-plugins 225](https://github.com/ProgVal/Supybot-plugins/issues/225#issuecomment-54752147):

> I contacted GitHub support and one of the employees has been troubleshooting this for me. Here is part of what he had to say about the issue:
>
> > I just tried making a request manually from one of our machines, and that went through with no error (see `curl -v` output below).
> > However, I did notice that it took extremely long for the request to be processed -- over 15 seconds (for 2 bytes of data).

Decoupling the listening and reception of the payload, from its proicessing, is generally the right approach, as I recommended ion "[Perl Script slow over Tomcat 6.0 and generates service time out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23824675/6309)".
The first part should be as fast as possible.